# I can't centre my div

Tags: html, css

I don't now what I'm doing wrong. I want the 'artikelen' div to be centered when it's opened. I've tried all kind of combinations but can't figure out what is going wrong.

**this is the HTML**

```
<nav class="cl-effect-1"><center>
                <a href="#artikelen"><span data-hover="Artikelen"><font size="1px">Artikelen</font></span></a>
                <a href="#drukwerk"><span data-hover="Drukwerk"><font size="1px">Drukwerk</font></span></a>
                <a href="#jaarverslagen"><span data-hover="Jaarverslagen"><font size="1px">Jaarverslagen</font></span></a>
                <a href="#mailings"><span data-hover="Mailings"><font size="1px">Mailings</font></span></a>
                <a href="#onderwijs"><span data-hover="Onderwijs"><font size="1px">Onderwijs</font></span></a>
              <a href="#webteksten"><span data-hover="Webteksten"><font size="1px">Webteksten</font></span></a>
            </center></nav>
<div id="artikelen">
<div class="inhoud">
Artikelen
</div>
</div>
```

**this is the CSS**

```
#artikelen {
position:absolute;
display:none;
width:auto;
height:auto;
}

#artikelen:target {
display:block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.inhoud {
background-color:black;
color: white;
width:200px;
height:150px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Try removing position:absolute from the #artikelen id http://jsfiddle.net/h8GL3/

Comment: OK so I posted that in an answer, would you mind accepting it as correct if this has fixed your issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/h8GL3/

I removed the

```
poistion:absolute
```

property from  #artikelen, and now the margin left and right works.